# show google maps, destination from URL

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to show a route on a map using google maps on my site. 
The start point is fixed but the end point will vary depending on a GET value from the URL. (I can also call the destination address from a mysql database). 
eg a user can choose a destination for a trip from a fixed hotel and I would like to show the route on a map for this. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little research and got on the google documantary: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=nl

I think this should help :)